# Getter returning Null in JSF but Setter Show the Value

Tags: jsf

I continually get null in the getter method on StudentBean but not on LoginBean. Would someone see if they can assist me with this?

--------------------code-----------------

---StudentBean---

```
package edu.jhu.jee;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.io.Serializable;

import edu.jhu.jee.LoginProg;
import edu.jhu.jee.SessionUtils;


@ManagedBean (name="studentBean")
@SessionScoped 

public class StudentBean implements Serializable {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        System.out.println("StudentBean getFirstName!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" +firstName);
        return this.firstName;      
    }   

    public String getLastName() {
        System.out.println("StudentBean getLastName!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"+lastName);
        return this.lastName;       
    }

    public void setFirstName(String first_Name) {
        this.firstName = first_Name;
        System.out.println("StudentBean setFirstName!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  "+firstName);       
    }


    public void setLastName(String last_Name) {
        this.lastName = last_Name;
        System.out.println("StudentBean setLastName!!!!!!!!!!!! "+lastName);
    }   

}
```

---LoginProg---

```
package edu.jhu.jee; 

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.Serializable;


public class LoginProg {

    public static String authenticate(String userid, String password) {



            String sqlStmt = null;

            Context ctx = null;
            Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
            ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
             "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
            ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://localhost:7001");
            Connection conn = null;
            Statement stmt = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            String st = null;

            sqlStmt = ("SELECT * FROM APP.STUDENT WHERE USERID='"+userid+"'AND PASSWORD='"+password+"'");
            try {
            ctx = new InitialContext(ht);

            javax.sql.DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup ("jhuDataSource");
            conn = ds.getConnection();
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            //  takes SQL statements from Login and Register servlets:          
                        rs =stmt.executeQuery(sqlStmt);


                        // Reads data objects in database Going Forward
                            while (rs.next()){
                                //Student object to fill with Student data
                                String first_name   = rs.getObject(3).toString();
                                String last_name    = rs.getObject(4).toString();
                                st = first_name + " " + last_name;
                                System.out.println(st);

                                StudentBean studentBean = new StudentBean();
                                studentBean.setFirstName(first_name);
                                studentBean.setLastName(last_name);


                            } 

                        if (st == null){ // check if user id exist at least
                        sqlStmt = ("SELECT * FROM APP.STUDENT WHERE USERID='"+userid+"'");
                        rs =stmt.executeQuery(sqlStmt);
                            while (rs.next()){
                                //Student object to fill with Student data
                                String user_id  = rs.getObject(1).toString();
                                st = user_id;
                                System.out.println("Password incorrect for "+st);
                            }
                        } else {} // Do nothing



            stmt.close();
            conn.close();

      }catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        finally {    
          try { 
            ctx.close(); 
          } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}
          try { 
            if (rs != null) rs.close(); 
          } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}
          try { 
            if (stmt != null) stmt.close(); 
          } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}
          try { 
            if (conn != null) conn.close(); 
          } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}
        }               

    return st;

    } 
}
```

-----welcome.xhtml-----

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" >



<h:head>
<title>Welcome</title>
<style>body {background-color: rgb(30, 145, 255);}</style>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form>
    <h2>Hello, #{studentBean.firstName} #{studentBean.lastName}!</h2>
    <h2>Hello, #{loginBean.userid} #{loginBean.password}!</h2>
    <h:panelGrid columns="1" border="0">
    <h:panelGroup>
        <h:outputText value="Select your next action: " />
            <h:selectOneRadio value = "#{userData.data}"> 
            <f:selectItem itemValue = "courseRegister" itemLabel = "Register for the course" /> 
            <f:selectItem itemValue = "logout" itemLabel = "Logout" />
        </h:selectOneRadio>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup>
        <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit" action="NextAction">
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGrid>

    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

--------------------end of code-----------------

I used SysOuts to print checkpoints trying to observe activities
From my JSF page to the beans kind of a working debug/tracer

This output is generate when my login.xhtml is submitted
and the LoginBean is loaded with the attributes:

```
LoginBean setUserid!!!!!!!!!!!!!!jd001_id

LoginBean setPassword!!!!!!!!!!!!jd001_pw
```

Database query result from my validation program

```
John_001 Doe_001
```

value sent to StudentBean by calling setter from Validation program:

```
StudentBean setFirstName!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  John_001

StudentBean setLastName!!!!!!!!!!!! Doe_001
```

welcome JSF page trying to retrieve name from StudentBean:

```
StudentBean getFirstName!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!null

StudentBean getLastName!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!null
```

Additional retrieval from login bean in welcome page 
showing successful attribute retrieval from LoginBean:

```
LoginBean getUserid!!!!!!!!!!!!jd001_id

LoginBean getPassword!!!!!!!jd001_pw
```

Comment: Can you post the validation program code where you are using the setters ?

Comment: please insert the login.xhtml and welcome.xhtml facelets

Comment: [mcve] please, and your debug output hard to read

Comment: Hi OTM and the Bitman, I have added the authenticating program and the welcome codes.

Comment: Hi Kukeltje - I have reorganized the sysouts for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a StudentBean "manually". It is wrong. The managed bean means : the container create them when the scope context created and the context will dispose them.

Use `@Named` instead of '@ManagedBean' (it will be depricated soon) and access the `StudentBean` instance in the `LoginProg.authenticate()` this way:

```
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession( true );
StudentBean studentBean = (StudentBean) session.getAttribute("studentBean");
if ( studentBean == null )
{
  studentBean = new StudentBean();
  session.setAttribute( "studentBean", studentBean );
}
studentBean.setFirstName( first_name );
...
```

The container should create the `studentBean` with the HttpSession instance but for sure I checked the bean existance (if it is null it creates an instance and put into the session scope context).

Comment: Hi Bitman, I tried it and end up getting compile error: Object cannot be converted to StudentBean. I am using a session utility not sure if I have to do anything there.

Comment: OK, I think I may have worked my way out of this issue by avoiding the StudentBean. I used LoginProg return element to provide the result back to LoginBean which made it available to the welcome page. Thanks for everyones input. Your comments and responses helped me resolve the issue. Thanks.

Comment: OK. I modified the answer and cast Object to StudentBean.

Comment: The best way to express your thanks here if you accept a working solution (regardless of you changed your mind meantime :) )

Comment: Thanks Bitman. The solution is indeed passing the attribute to the session because the getters didn't work possible due to instance mismatch. The session.setAttribute( "studentBean", studentBean ); makes the attribute available for use in the jsf page. Thanks again.